# database to web3.eth security?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, security, dapps

If I am pulling in data from SQL and sending it to a contract using web3.eth, can the data be manipulated in anyway, between the SQL->Arrival at Ethereum contract bridge?

Answer (score 2):

The contact bridge is an HTTP server: if the connection is unsecured the data can be manipulated by a man in the middle.